# My Error is JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android

I am new to JSON and I am getting the following Exception:

`org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` in the first line of try section itself.

Please help me to remove this. Here's my code:

```
public void sendjsonrequest(){
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("dish");
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                     JSONObject dishes = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                      int  idd = dishes.getInt("id");
                      String  latitude = dishes.getString("latitude");
                      String  longitude = dishes.getString("longitude");
                     String   snip = dishes.getString("snippet");
                        id.append(idd+","+latitude+","+longitude+","+snip+"");                      //  id.setText(idd);
                      //  lat.setText(latitude);
                      //  lon.setText(longitude);
                      //  snippet.setText(snip);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

this is the json I am getting from my php file

```
[{"id":"3","latitude":"Latitude: 11.913859799999999","longitude":"Longitude: 79.8144722","snippet":"I am Here"}]
```

Comment: I don't see any `dish` field in your JSON.

Comment: dish is not show in give json format.

Comment: yup actually i changed it to my url name. but still am not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

Change **response** in parameter to `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`.
Change **JsonObjectRequest**  in to `JsonArrayRequest` .

Your JSON :

```
[{"id":"3","latitude":"Latitude: 11.913859799999999","longitude":"Longitude: 79.8144722","snippet":"I am Here"}]
```

Code :

```
    public void sendjsonrequest(){

        JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) { // Change it here
                try {
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject dishes = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int  idd = dishes.getInt("id");
                        String  latitude = dishes.getDouble("latitude") +"";
                        String  longitude = dishes.getDouble("longitude") + "";
                        String   snip = dishes.getString("snippet");
                        id.append(idd+","+latitude+","+longitude+","+snip+"");                      //  id.setText(idd);
                        //  lat.setText(latitude);
                        //  lon.setText(longitude);
                        //  snippet.setText(snip);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Still am getting the same error

Comment: can you post exact string of response?

Comment: and post the exception you are getting in logs

Comment: public void sendjsonrequest(){
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());

                    JSONObject dishes = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

Comment: Put this line : Log.d("response", response+""); after  'try {" , and write that string here from logCat

Comment: Use my updated answer

Comment: dude am not getting anything about responce in log cat

Comment: try after changing JsonObjectRequest in to JsonArrayRequest.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/ use this for reference

Comment: Really thanks dude. it works when i converted it to jsonarrayrequest.